# Why does destroy() not work in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, destroy

This is a simple test script I am attempting to write which will help me teach myself about tkinter...

```
from tkinter import *
def hello():
   print("U pressed it lol")

global window1, window2
window2 = None
window1 = None

def setWindow(windowEnter):
   global window
   window = windowEnter
   window = Tk()
   window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

def newScreen(newScreen, screenToDelete):
   setWindow(newScreen)
   print("New Window Created")
   screenToDelete.destroy()
   print("He ded lol")

setWindow(window1)

def setStuff():
   button = Button(window1, text="hey", command=hello)
   label = Label(window1, text="YoYoYo My dude")
   button2 = Button(window1, text="Next Page", command = lambda: newScreen(window2, window1))

   button.pack()
   label.pack()
   button2.pack()

setStuff()
```

When I run this code it returns an error?

```
File "C:\Users\026341\Desktop\test.py", line 19, in newScreen
screenToDelete.destroy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

Why doesn't this work & how do i fix it?

Thanks in advance :)
(Btw I'm using python 3.6)

Comment: Is this your full code? You never set window 1 and window 2 to anything other than `None` (Am I overlooking something?) which might be the issue

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes, this is the full code... how would i go about setting them whilst still allowing for the functions like setWindow() to work?

Comment: hold on, writing a more elaborate answer

Comment: The error literally answers the question in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set

```
window2 = None
window1 = None
```

as global variables and then define the command function for `button2` to be

```
lambda: newScreen(window2, window1)
```

Which calls `newScreen` with the values window2 and window1 which are both `None`, hence the error. The underlying issue here is your `setWindow` function:

```
def setWindow(windowEnter):
    global window
    window = windowEnter
    window = Tk()
    window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
```

which doesn't work the way you are using it. When you call `setWindow(window1)`, you pass the **value** of `window1`, what the function does with the variable cannot be seen on a global scope. A quick example would be this:

```
def increment(a):
    a +=1
x = 1
print(x)
increment(x)
print(x)
```

which will print 1 twice.

To achieve what you want I suggest you use a dictionary to keep track of your windows.

```
from tkinter import *
def hello():
   print("U pressed it lol")

global window1, window2
windows = {}


def setWindow(window_name):
   windows[window_name] = Tk()
   windows[window_name].attributes("-fullscreen", True)

def newScreen(newScreen_name, screenToDelete_name):
   setWindow(newScreen_name)
   print("New Window Created")
   windows[screenToDelete_name].destroy()
   del windows[screenToDelete_name] #delete invalid entry from dict
   print("He ded lol")

setWindow("window1")

def setStuff():
   button = Button(windows["window1"], text="hey", command=hello)
   label = Label(windows["window1"], text="YoYoYo My dude")
   button2 = Button(windows["window1"], text="Next Page", command = lambda: newScreen("window2", "window1"))

   button.pack()
   label.pack()
   button2.pack()

setStuff()
```

**Note on the side:** previously your function was `def newScreen(newScreen, screenToDelete)`, which is very confusing/bad style since both the function and its first argument share the same name. I changed it anyway to highlight that it now takes strings as arguments, but keep it in mind for the furture.

Comment: Thanks tons!  Now I can get on with my assignment!

Comment: @Jake you are welcome. Take note of the two edits I just made.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to test it right now, but I've spotted a source of error:

```
lambda: newScreen(window2, window1)
```

This creates a lambda function that doesn't take any arguments, hence window2 and window1 will be None, and None doesn't have a destroy() method, hence the error. Instead try:

```
lambda window2, window1: newScreen(window2, window1)
```

Comment: This returns the error: TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'window2' and 'window1'

Comment: Ah yes, of course, I rushed through this and should have tested. @FlyingTeller gave a great answer.